# How to perform symmetric key encryption on a flutter web project? (dart2js)

Tags: flutter, encryption, flutter-web, dart2js

Currently flutter web encryption/decryption fails due to unimplemented datatype. "Unsupported operation: Uint64 accessor not supported by dart2js."

I want to run the following code from the [encrypt](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt) flutter package in my flutter web app.

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';

void main() {
  final plainText = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit';
  final key = Key.fromUtf8('my 32 length key................');
  final iv = IV.fromLength(16);

  final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));

  final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);
  final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: iv);

  print(decrypted); // Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
  print(encrypted.base64); // R4PxiU3h8YoIRqVowBXm36ZcCeNeZ4s1OvVBTfFlZRdmohQqOpPQqD1YecJeZMAop/hZ4OxqgC1WtwvX/hP9mw==
}
```

When running the app on the browser the code will fail due to an unimplemented data type.
error: "Unsupported operation: Uint64 accessor not supported by dart2js."
[This is a well-known issue and it does not appear there are plans to implement these datatypes.](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/10275)

[The fernet specification requires a 64bit timestamp as part of its token.](https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md#token-format)

I'm hoping to find a suitable alternative to perform symmetric key encryption on a flutter web app.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, did you find a workaround?

Comment: Afraid not, I had to abandon this approach.

Comment: Depending on your usecase, have you thought of outsourcing this task? 

In my case, I want to encrypt a users data and store it to firebase. My workaround now is to run this encryption with a cloud function.